# Why does setTimeOut not work with my recreated promise function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I tried recreating the Promise class of javascript with the class keyword and function closure, it works with promise functions that returns instantly, but does not work with setTimeOut. I tried adding console.log into the setTimeOut function to check, it does not even print when the time is up. Is it because of the while loop that checks for change of state in myPromise class?

```js
// custom promise function
class MyPromise {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
  }

  resolveWrapper() {
    var state = 'pending';
    var value = '';

    function myResolve(val) {
      value = val;
      state = 'resolved';
    }

    function myReject(val) {
      value = val;
      state = 'rejected';
    }

    function getStateValue() {
      let stateValue = {
        state: state,
        value: value,
      }
      return stateValue;
    }

    let returnVal = {
      resolve: myResolve,
      reject: myReject,
      getter: getStateValue,
    }

    return returnVal;
  }

  then(nextFunc) {
    let stateValue = this.resolveWrapper();
    let getter = stateValue.getter;
    this.func(stateValue.resolve, stateValue.reject);

    while (getter().state === 'pending') {
      // keep checking
    }
    return nextFunc(getter.value);
  }
}
// test
let newProm = new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
    resolve('1');
  }, 1000);
})

let tst = newProm.then((val) => (console.log(val)));

console.log(tst);
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded without preemption. Your `while` loop never allows the timeout function to run.

Comment: ^^ what Barmar said. (Well, single-threaded *per realm*. You can have multiple threads, they just don't share a common global environment and communicate via messaging.) Separately: I suggest have a really, really deep read through the MDN docs on promises. There's no need for your loop at all. Store the functions you're passed in the call to then (both of them), and call them (asynchronously) when appropriate as a result of the `resolve` or `reject` functions that you pass the promise executor do.

Comment: You need to implement promises on top of callbacks. There's no way around this. JS is non-blocking.

Comment: That y'all for all the replies! I read through some more explanations on how javascript multi-thread works and this is my understanding of why this does not work, could you have a look if it is correct?
1. setTimeOut function starts to get processed in another thread
2. while loop starts running, taking up the call stack
3. setTimeOut function is done, and the code inside is pushed to the call stack
4. but the while loop is occupying the bottom of call stack, so the inside of setTimeOut never got executed

Comment: @NanyuDing Roughly. 1. `setTimeout` is implemented using OS-level asynchronous timers, it's not a thread keeping the cpu busy for 1s 3. the `setTimeout` callback is pushed to the *event queue*, not to the call stack. The queue is processed when the call stack becomes empty, so your conclusion is still right though